# Bitdefender blocks gmod update file

Tags: windows-10, anti-virus, steam, bitdefender

I haven't used Steam for a week or so, but a "gift" is presented to me on my return:

> An error occurred while updating Garry's Mod (disk write error)

After reading [Steam Support's article](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=9709-FKCB-4230) on this error, I've tried scanning my drive for errors, tried deleting Steam's `appcache` folder, deleting and restarting the download (with and without antivirus on), but to no avail.

The output from my `content_log.txt` says nothing about a locked file, it just says that it failed to find `hl2.exe` which is the executable file.

---

What I **do know** is that my antivirus (Bitdefender Free Edition) may be interfering in some way.  Bitdefender quarantined the file, so I tried restoring it, but Bitdefender refuses to release the file.

---

**What I'm looking for:**

- Confirm Bitdefender's role in this. If it is interfering, how do I stop it from quarantining the file?
- If not, what is the root of the problem?

**Specs**: gmod - December 2015 update, Windows 10 Pro, Steam - December 14 build, Samsung MZMTE128HMGR-000MV solid state hard drive

---

**Note:**
I considered posting this on [Arqade](http://gaming.stackexchange.com), but this doesn't have to do with the game itself.  It's rather a problem with software interfering with writing the file or hardware problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 days after I posted this question, gmod released an announcement that some of its latest update files may be marked as a virus.

Yesterday, Bitdefender performed a virus definition update (version `7.63851`). Sure enough, the false positive was fixed.